# Bluetooth COD on WinCE, connect by Apple mobile device

Tags: ios, bluetooth, windows-ce

I would like to use a Apple mobile device (iPhone, iPod touch) to connect to a Windows CE device via bluetooth, but it failed.  Iphone returns an error message that the device is not supported.

I understand about the MFI process but it's too difficult to get approval from the Apple MFi Team for a Windows CE device so I don't even bother to try.

Another way is change the bluetooth profile in the WinCE so make it as a headset or bluetooth keyboard so hopefully Apple can discover it as another device and accept the connection.  I have the CERegEditor to modify the registry and also a COD generator from this link (http://bluetooth-pentest.narod.ru/software/bluetooth_class_of_device-service_generator.html).  I modify the bluetooth profile successfully on the device and verified by Android.  However, I'm still not able to use a iPhone to connect to it.

I tried to make it as a wireless headset or hands-free but it's not discoverable by the iPhone, or it just directly refused to connect.

If I made it as a keyboard, it's discoverable by the iPhone, but it doesn't connect after I send a pair request and type in the correct 4-digit pin.  iPhone returns the "out of range" error even it's just next to it.

I hope I can get some help here.  I appreciate if anyone can share similar experience before or provide me an appropriate COD code which works for you, or any other methods that can let me to make a connection.

Thanks for your attention.